# Ubuntu Studio Login Screen Missing?

Tags: login-screen, gdm, ubuntu-studio

Just upgraded my machine to Ubuntu Studio (10.10), and am starting to learn my way around.

One thing I noticed off-the-bat is that the GDM login screen promoted on the Studio site is missing (http://ubuntustudio.org/files/US3.png)

Anyone know how I can get/find/activate it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Studio, Ubuntu 10.10 (Gnome).

`apt-cache search ubuntustudio` reveals some packages.

```
ubuntustudio-desktop
ubuntustudio-font-meta
ubuntustudio-gdm-theme
ubuntustudio-graphics
ubuntustudio-icon-theme
ubuntustudio-look
ubuntustudio-menu
ubuntustudio-screensaver
ubuntustudio-sounds
ubuntustudio-theme
ubuntustudio-video
ubuntustudio-wallpapers
```

I've installed Studio before, but never wound up without those things.
Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have enabled automatic logging in? Go to System->Administration->Login Screen and check if "Log in as  automatically" is enabled.